# How to show that two groups are not isomorphic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism, direct-sum

I have learned various theorems that tell me when two groups are isomorphic. For example, if the greatest common divisor of $j$ and $k$ is equal to one, then $\mathbb{Z}_j\oplus\mathbb{Z}_k\cong\mathbb{Z}_{jk}$. This tells us, for instance, that $\mathbb{Z}_3\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{25}\cong\mathbb{Z}_{75}$. However, how can I show that $\mathbb{Z}_5\oplus\mathbb{Z}_{15}$ is *not* isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{75}$?

Comment: What are the orders of the elements of $\Bbb Z_5 \oplus \Bbb Z_{15}$? In particular, does that group have any element of order $75$?

Comment: It hasn't got an element of order $75$.  Your broader question, however, is not generally solvable.  Even the simpler sounding question, "given the generators and relations that define a group, can I tell if the group is trivial?" is too hard.

Comment: @TravisWillse, Thank you.

Comment: Cf. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/955577/mathbbz-mathbb2z-bigoplus-mathbbz-mathbb2z-not-isomorphic-to-ma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\mathbb{Z}_{75}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{15}$, $\mathbb{Z}_5 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ has a element of order $75$.

But for all $(x,y) \in \mathbb{Z}_5 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{15}$, the order of $x$ is $5$ and the order of $y$ is $1$, $3$, $5$, or $15$. Therefore, the order of $(x,y)$ is at most $15$.

This is contradiction.
Hence, $\mathbb{Z}_{75}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{15}$

Comment: I'm not quite sure why the order of $y$ is $3$ or $5$. The order is the lowest $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $k\cdot y=0$. But if we consider $y=13$, then $3\cdot y=9$ and $5\cdot y=5$. The order of $13$ is $15$, if I'm not wrong?

Comment: I do agree, however, that the highest order of $(x,y)$ is 15.

Comment: Sorry, I missed. The order of $(x,y)$ is $1$, $3$, $5$ or $15$.